# beerscript.js:45 Uncaught ReferenceError: DOMStrings is not defined at beerscript.js:45 at beerscript.js:54

Tags: javascript

```js
var budgetController = (function()
{     
   //code here

})();

//ui  controller
var UIController = (function() {
    var DOMStrings = {
        inputType: '.add__type',
        inputDescription: '.add__description',
        inputValue: '.add__value',
        inputBtn:'.add__btn'
    };

    return {
        getInput: function() {
           return {
            type: document.querySelector(DOMStrings.inputType).value,
            description: document.querySelector(DOMStrings.inputDescription).value,
            value: document.querySelector(DOMStrings.inputValue).value

           };
        },

        getDOMstrings: function(){
            return DOMStrings;
        }
    };

})();

var Controller = (function(budgetCtrl,UICtrl){
  var DOM = UICtrl.getDOMstrings;

  var ctrlAddItem = function() {
     var input = UICtrl.getInput();
        console.log(input);
   //2. pass it to the budget controller.
   //3. update user interface.
   //4 calculate budget
   //5 update budget
   }
    
   document.querySelector(DOM.inputBtn).addEventListener('click', ctrlAddItem);
   document.addEventListener('keypress',function(event){

     if(event.keycode === 13 || event.which === 13){
        ctrlAddItem();
    }

 });

})(budgetController,UIController);
```

```css
/**********************************************
*** GENERAL
**********************************************/

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.clearfix::after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

body {
    color: #555;
    font-family: Open Sans;
    font-size: 16px;
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
    font-weight: 400;
}

.right { float: right; }
.red { color: #FF5049 !important; }
.red-focus:focus { border: 1px solid #FF5049 !important; }

/**********************************************
*** TOP PART
**********************************************/

.top {
    height: 40vh;
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35)), url(back.png);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    position: relative;
}

.budget {
    position: absolute;
    width: 350px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    color: #fff;
}

.budget__title {
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-weight: 300;
}

.budget__value {
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 46px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.budget__income,
.budget__expenses {
    padding: 12px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.budget__income {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background-color: #28B9B5;
}

.budget__expenses {
    background-color: #FF5049;
}

.budget__income--text,
.budget__expenses--text {
    float: left;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #444;
    margin-top: 2px;
}

.budget__income--value,
.budget__expenses--value {
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    float: left;
}

.budget__income--percentage,
.budget__expenses--percentage {
    float: left;
    width: 34px;
    font-size: 11px;
    padding: 3px 0;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.budget__expenses--percentage {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 3px;
}


/**********************************************
*** BOTTOM PART
**********************************************/

/***** FORM *****/
.add {
    padding: 14px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
}

.add__container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.add__type {
    width: 55px;
    border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
    height: 44px;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: inherit;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin-right: 10px;
    font-weight: 300;
    transition: border 0.3s;
}

.add__description,
.add__value {
    border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: inherit;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 12px 15px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    transition: border 0.3s;
}

.add__description { width: 400px;}
.add__value { width: 100px;}

.add__btn {
    font-size: 35px;
    background: none;
    border: none;
    color: #28B9B5;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 1.1;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.add__btn:active { transform: translateY(2px); }

.add__type:focus,
.add__description:focus,
.add__value:focus {
    outline: none;
    border: 1px solid #28B9B5;
}

.add__btn:focus { outline: none; }

/***** LISTS *****/
.container {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 60px auto;
}

.income {
    float: left;
    width: 475px;
    margin-right: 50px;
}

.expenses {
    float: left;
    width: 475px;
}

h2 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.icome__title { color: #28B9B5; }
.expenses__title { color: #FF5049; }

.item {
    padding: 13px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
}

.item:first-child { border-top: 1px solid #e7e7e7; }
.item:nth-child(even) { background-color: #f7f7f7; }

.item__description {
    float: left;
}

.item__value {
    float: left;
    transition: transform 0.3s;
}

.item__percentage {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 20px;
    transition: transform 0.3s;
    font-size: 11px;
    background-color: #FFDAD9;
    padding: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    width: 32px;
    text-align: center;
}

.income .item__value,
.income .item__delete--btn {
    color: #28B9B5;
}

.expenses .item__value,
.expenses .item__percentage,
.expenses .item__delete--btn {
    color: #FF5049;
}


.item__delete {
    float: left;
}

.item__delete--btn {
    font-size: 22px;
    background: none;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 1;
    display: none;
}

.item__delete--btn:focus { outline: none; }
.item__delete--btn:active { transform: translateY(2px); }

.item:hover .item__delete--btn { display: block; }
.item:hover .item__value { transform: translateX(-20px); }
.item:hover .item__percentage { transform: translateX(-20px); }


.unpaid {
    background-color: #FFDAD9 !important;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #FF5049;

}

.unpaid .item__percentage { box-shadow: 0 2px 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); }
.unpaid:hover .item__description { font-weight: 900; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:100,300,400,600" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <title>Budgety</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <div class="top">
            <div class="budget">
                <div class="budget__title">
                    Available Budget in <span class="budget__title--month">%Month%</span>:
                </div>
                
                <div class="budget__value">+ 2,345.64</div>
                
                <div class="budget__income clearfix">
                    <div class="budget__income--text">Income</div>
                    <div class="right">
                        <div class="budget__income--value">+ 4,300.00</div>
                        <div class="budget__income--percentage">&nbsp;</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="budget__expenses clearfix">
                    <div class="budget__expenses--text">Expenses</div>
                    <div class="right clearfix">
                        <div class="budget__expenses--value">- 1,954.36</div>
                        <div class="budget__expenses--percentage">45%</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        
        
        <div class="bottom">
            <div class="add">
                <div class="add__container">
                    <select class="add__type">
                        <option value="inc" selected>+</option>
                        <option value="exp">-</option>
                    </select>
                    <input type="text" class="add__description" placeholder="Add description">
                    <input type="number" class="add__value" placeholder="Value">
                    <button class="add__btn"><i class="ion-ios-checkmark-outline"></i></button>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="container clearfix">
                <div class="income">
                    <h2 class="icome__title">Income</h2>
                    
                    <div class="income__list">
                       
                        <!--
                        <div class="item clearfix" id="income-0">
                            <div class="item__description">Salary</div>
                            <div class="right clearfix">
                                <div class="item__value">+ 2,100.00</div>
                                <div class="item__delete">
                                    <button class="item__delete--btn"><i class="ion-ios-close-outline"></i></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="item clearfix" id="income-1">
                            <div class="item__description">Sold car</div>
                            <div class="right clearfix">
                                <div class="item__value">+ 1,500.00</div>
                                <div class="item__delete">
                                    <button class="item__delete--btn"><i class="ion-ios-close-outline"></i></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        -->
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                
                
                <div class="expenses">
                    <h2 class="expenses__title">Expenses</h2>
                    
                    <div class="expenses__list">
                       
                        <!--
                        <div class="item clearfix" id="expense-0">
                            <div class="item__description">Apartment rent</div>
                            <div class="right clearfix">
                                <div class="item__value">- 900.00</div>
                                <div class="item__percentage">21%</div>
                                <div class="item__delete">
                                    <button class="item__delete--btn"><i class="ion-ios-close-outline"></i></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="item clearfix" id="expense-1">
                            <div class="item__description">Grocery shopping</div>
                            <div class="right clearfix">
                                <div class="item__value">- 435.28</div>
                                <div class="item__percentage">10%</div>
                                <div class="item__delete">
                                    <button class="item__delete--btn"><i class="ion-ios-close-outline"></i></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        -->
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            
        </div>
        
        
    </body>



    <script src="beerscript.js"></script>
</html>
```

i get error beerscript.js:45 Uncaught ReferenceError: DOMStrings is not defined.

im using iffie and closures. im passing one module functon to an other module but i get error. i believe i have the code written exactly how it is in the lesson.  i cant find the error.  the lesson is from UDEMY instructor Jonas

Comment: You're trying to reference `DOMStrings.inputBtn` in Controller, but it's only defined in UIController

Comment: You probably mean to do something like `UIctrl.getDOMstrings().inputBtn`

Comment: OK i edit the JS file to use DOM. inputBtn. on the event listener , i still get the same error

Answer (score 1):

`Controller` doesn't know about `DOMStrings` since it's in the closure of `UIController`. `UIController` has a method `getDOMstrings`, which returns the object, just use it - you actually almost had the solution (see the two commented js lines). :)

```js
var budgetController = (function() {
  //code here

})();

//ui  controller
var UIController = (function() {
  var DOMStrings = {
    inputType: '.add__type',
    inputDescription: '.add__description',
    inputValue: '.add__value',
    inputBtn: '.add__btn'
  };

  return {
    getInput: function() {
      return {
        type: document.querySelector(DOMStrings.inputType).value,
        description: document.querySelector(DOMStrings.inputDescription).value,
        value: document.querySelector(DOMStrings.inputValue).value

      };
    },

    getDOMstrings: function() {
      return DOMStrings;
    }
  };

})();

var Controller = (function(budgetCtrl, UIctrl) {
  // FIX: UIctrl.getDomstring to UIctrl.getDOMstrings();
  var DOM = UIctrl.getDOMstrings();


  var ctrlAddItem = function() {
    var input = UIctrl.getInput();
    console.log(input);
    //2. pass it to the budget controller.
    //3. update user interface.
    //4 calculate budget
    //5 update budget
  }

  // FIX: Now you can use the object DOM to get the value.
  document.querySelector(DOM.inputBtn).addEventListener('click', ctrlAddItem)
  document.addEventListener('keypress', function(event) {

    if (event.keycode === 13 || event.which === 13) {
      ctrlAddItem();
    }

  });

})(budgetController, UIController);
```

```css
/**********************************************
*** GENERAL
**********************************************/

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.clearfix::after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

body {
  color: #555;
  font-family: Open Sans;
  font-size: 16px;
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.right {
  float: right;
}

.red {
  color: #FF5049 !important;
}

.red-focus:focus {
  border: 1px solid #FF5049 !important;
}


/**********************************************
*** TOP PART
**********************************************/

.top {
  height: 40vh;
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35)), url(back.png);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  position: relative;
}

.budget {
  position: absolute;
  width: 350px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: #fff;
}

.budget__title {
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.budget__value {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 46px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.budget__income,
.budget__expenses {
  padding: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.budget__income {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: #28B9B5;
}

.budget__expenses {
  background-color: #FF5049;
}

.budget__income--text,
.budget__expenses--text {
  float: left;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #444;
  margin-top: 2px;
}

.budget__income--value,
.budget__expenses--value {
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  float: left;
}

.budget__income--percentage,
.budget__expenses--percentage {
  float: left;
  width: 34px;
  font-size: 11px;
  padding: 3px 0;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.budget__expenses--percentage {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 3px;
}


/**********************************************
*** BOTTOM PART
**********************************************/


/***** FORM *****/

.add {
  padding: 14px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
}

.add__container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.add__type {
  width: 55px;
  border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
  height: 44px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: inherit;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-weight: 300;
  transition: border 0.3s;
}

.add__description,
.add__value {
  border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 12px 15px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: border 0.3s;
}

.add__description {
  width: 400px;
}

.add__value {
  width: 100px;
}

.add__btn {
  font-size: 35px;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  color: #28B9B5;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 1.1;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.add__btn:active {
  transform: translateY(2px);
}

.add__type:focus,
.add__description:focus,
.add__value:focus {
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid #28B9B5;
}

.add__btn:focus {
  outline: none;
}


/***** LISTS *****/

.container {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 60px auto;
}

.income {
  float: left;
  width: 475px;
  margin-right: 50px;
}

.expenses {
  float: left;
  width: 475px;
}

h2 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.icome__title {
  color: #28B9B5;
}

.expenses__title {
  color: #FF5049;
}

.item {
  padding: 13px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
}

.item:first-child {
  border-top: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
}

.item:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
}

.item__description {
  float: left;
}

.item__value {
  float: left;
  transition: transform 0.3s;
}

.item__percentage {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 20px;
  transition: transform 0.3s;
  font-size: 11px;
  background-color: #FFDAD9;
  padding: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 32px;
  text-align: center;
}

.income .item__value,
.income .item__delete--btn {
  color: #28B9B5;
}

.expenses .item__value,
.expenses .item__percentage,
.expenses .item__delete--btn {
  color: #FF5049;
}

.item__delete {
  float: left;
}

.item__delete--btn {
  font-size: 22px;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 1;
  display: none;
}

.item__delete--btn:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.item__delete--btn:active {
  transform: translateY(2px);
}

.item:hover .item__delete--btn {
  display: block;
}

.item:hover .item__value {
  transform: translateX(-20px);
}

.item:hover .item__percentage {
  transform: translateX(-20px);
}

.unpaid {
  background-color: #FFDAD9 !important;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #FF5049;
}

.unpaid .item__percentage {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.unpaid:hover .item__description {
  font-weight: 900;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:100,300,400,600" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Budgety</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="top">
    <div class="budget">
      <div class="budget__title">
        Available Budget in <span class="budget__title--month">%Month%</span>:
      </div>

      <div class="budget__value">+ 2,345.64</div>

      <div class="budget__income clearfix">
        <div class="budget__income--text">Income</div>
        <div class="right">
          <div class="budget__income--value">+ 4,300.00</div>
          <div class="budget__income--percentage">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="budget__expenses clearfix">
        <div class="budget__expenses--text">Expenses</div>
        <div class="right clearfix">
          <div class="budget__expenses--value">- 1,954.36</div>
          <div class="budget__expenses--percentage">45%</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>



  <div class="bottom">
    <div class="add">
      <div class="add__container">
        <select class="add__type">
          <option value="inc" selected>+</option>
          <option value="exp">-</option>
        </select>
        <input type="text" class="add__description" placeholder="Add description">
        <input type="number" class="add__value" placeholder="Value">
        <button class="add__btn"><i class="ion-ios-checkmark-outline"></i></button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container clearfix">
      <div class="income">
        <h2 class="icome__title">Income</h2>

        <div class="income__list">

          <!--
                        <div class="item clearfix" id="income-0">
                            <div class="item__description">Salary</div>
                            <div class="right clearfix">
                                <div class="item__value">+ 2,100.00</div>
                                <div class="item__delete">
                                    <button class="item__delete--btn"><i class="ion-ios-close-outline"></i></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="item clearfix" id="income-1">
                            <div class="item__description">Sold car</div>
                            <div class="right clearfix">
                                <div class="item__value">+ 1,500.00</div>
                                <div class="item__delete">
                                    <button class="item__delete--btn"><i class="ion-ios-close-outline"></i></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        -->

        </div>
      </div>



      <div class="expenses">
        <h2 class="expenses__title">Expenses</h2>

        <div class="expenses__list">

          <!--
                        <div class="item clearfix" id="expense-0">
                            <div class="item__description">Apartment rent</div>
                            <div class="right clearfix">
                                <div class="item__value">- 900.00</div>
                                <div class="item__percentage">21%</div>
                                <div class="item__delete">
                                    <button class="item__delete--btn"><i class="ion-ios-close-outline"></i></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="item clearfix" id="expense-1">
                            <div class="item__description">Grocery shopping</div>
                            <div class="right clearfix">
                                <div class="item__value">- 435.28</div>
                                <div class="item__percentage">10%</div>
                                <div class="item__delete">
                                    <button class="item__delete--btn"><i class="ion-ios-close-outline"></i></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        -->

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


  </div>

  <script src="beerscript.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```